# Threads module giving error of channel closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, js-xlsx

I am using the npm xlsx (lib/parserScripts/readExcel.js)
and threads module to read a large excel file.

This works fine for the first time but if I simultaneously upload another large file then I get an error

```
Error: channel closed
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:554:16)
    at Worker.send (/app/node_modules/threads/lib/worker.node/worker.js:108:16)...
```

This is maybe due to the previous threads are still processing /have not been killed hence when a new pool is made for another request the previous threads are still busy processing.

How to solve this? Do I have to manually terminate the threads in the below piece of code? If so then how?

**index.js**

```
    parseFile: ['fileHeaders', (results, cb) => {
        const excelParserScript = __dirname + '/../lib/parserScripts/readExcel';
        const worksheetIndex = 3;
        const params = {
            file.path,
            worksheetIndex
        }

        // using worker process
        // result will be of the type {error: false, message: '', data: {}}
        lib.miniWorker.bufferedJob(excelParserScript, params, (err, result) => {
```

**lib/miniworker.js**

```
const Threads = require('threads');
const Pool = Threads.Pool; 
const workerPool = new Pool();

module.exports = class JobManager {
    static bufferedJob(pathToScript, params, callback){
        workerPool
        .run(pathToScript)
        .send(params)
        .on('done', (result, input) => {
            console.log(`Worker Job done: ${pathToScript} `);
            callback(null, result);
        })
        .on('error', (job, error) => {
            console.log(`Error in executing Worker Job: ${pathToScript}`);
            callback(job || error);
        })
    }
}
```

**`lib/parserScripts/readExcel.js`**

```
module.exports = function(input, done) {
    const XLSX = require('xlsx');

    let workbook;
    const path = input.path;

    const worksheetIndex = input.worksheetIndex;
    const expectedHeaders = input.expectedHeaders || [];
    const options = {};
    if (expectedHeaders.length > 0) {
        options.header = expectedHeaders;
    }
    const response = {
        error: false,
        message: '',
        data: {}
    }

    try {

        workbook = XLSX.readFile(path, {});
        const sheet = workbook['Sheets'][workbook.SheetNames[worksheetIndex]];
        const headers = getHeaders(sheet);
        const fileData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook['Sheets'][workbook.SheetNames[worksheetIndex]], options);
        response.data = fileData;
        response.headers = headers;
        return done(response)

    } catch (err) {

        response.error = true;
        response.messsage = 'Error in reading the file';
        return done(response);

    }


    function getHeaders(sheet) {
        var header = 0, offset = 1;
        var hdr = [];
        var o = {};
        if (sheet == null || sheet["!ref"] == null) return [];
        var range = o.range !== undefined ? o.range : sheet["!ref"];
        var r;
        if (o.header === 1) header = 1;
        else if (o.header === "A") header = 2;
        else if (Array.isArray(o.header)) header = 3;
        switch (typeof range) {
            case 'string':
                r = safe_decode_range(range);
                break;
            case 'number':
                r = safe_decode_range(sheet["!ref"]);
                r.s.r = range;
                break;
            default:
                r = range;
        }
        if (header > 0) offset = 0;
        var rr = XLSX.utils.encode_row(r.s.r);
        var cols = new Array(r.e.c - r.s.c + 1);
        for (var C = r.s.c; C <= r.e.c; ++C) {
            cols[C] = XLSX.utils.encode_col(C);
            var val = sheet[cols[C] + rr];
            switch (header) {
                case 1:
                    hdr.push(C);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    hdr.push(cols[C]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    hdr.push(o.header[C - r.s.c]);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (val === undefined) continue;
                    hdr.push(XLSX.utils.format_cell(val));
            }
        }
        return hdr;
    }


    function safe_decode_range(range) {
        var o = {s: {c: 0, r: 0}, e: {c: 0, r: 0}};
        var idx = 0, i = 0, cc = 0;
        var len = range.length;
        for (idx = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if ((cc = range.charCodeAt(i) - 64) < 1 || cc > 26) break;
            idx = 26 * idx + cc;
        }
        o.s.c = --idx;

        for (idx = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if ((cc = range.charCodeAt(i) - 48) < 0 || cc > 9) break;
            idx = 10 * idx + cc;
        }
        o.s.r = --idx;

        if (i === len || range.charCodeAt(++i) === 58) {
            o.e.c = o.s.c;
            o.e.r = o.s.r;
            return o;
        }

        for (idx = 0; i != len; ++i) {
            if ((cc = range.charCodeAt(i) - 64) < 1 || cc > 26) break;
            idx = 26 * idx + cc;
        }
        o.e.c = --idx;

        for (idx = 0; i != len; ++i) {
            if ((cc = range.charCodeAt(i) - 48) < 0 || cc > 9) break;
            idx = 10 * idx + cc;
        }
        o.e.r = --idx;
        return o;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't find any reference about the way you are doing this. What library are you using?

Comment: Please check lib/parserScripts/readExcel.js I have used xlsx to read file @EternalHour

Comment: I find nothing. I would suggest you provide a link to the documentation. This doesn't appear to be a widely known method of parsing an excel file.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx npm package for reading excel file and https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads to process it on worker threads.@EternalHour

Comment: And https://www.npmjs.com/package/job-manager?

Comment: No havent used job-manager @EternalHour.Please revisit the question I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue is because of the older version module of threads. Updating to the new version and using the updated API which is not event-based can solve the purpose.**

https://github.com/andywer/threads.js/issues/164

However, if you want to correct the event-based code(from older version) this is what you need to do (kill the threads after the event gets completed).

```
const Threads = require('threads');
const Pool = Threads.Pool; 


module.exports = class JobManager {
    static bufferedJob(pathToScript, params, callback){
        let workerPool = new Pool();
        workerPool
        .run(pathToScript)
        .send(params)
        .on('done', (result, input) => {
            console.log(`Worker Job done: ${pathToScript} `);
            callback(null, result);
            workerPool.killAll();
            workerPool = null ;
        })
        .on('error', (job, error) => {
            console.log(`Error in executing Worker Job: ${pathToScript}`);
            callback(job || error);
            workerPool.killAll();
            workerPool = null ;
        }).on('abort',  (job, error)=>{
            console.log(`Abort Worker Job: ${pathToScript}, Error : ${error}`);
            callback(job || error);
            workerPool.killAll();
            workerPool = null ;
        }).on('finished', ()=>{
            console.log('Everything done, shutting down the thread pool.');
            workerPool.killAll();
          });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for the first time but if I simultaneously **upload** another large file then I get an error.

you should upload a different file name like a final01.xlsx and then rename it to final.xlsx
The reason being when you upload file the readfile cant finish as writing a file locks the file and change content.
If upload file means you are simultaneously reading another large file in node.js code ignore my comment.